# CSS conditional effect?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

The following code is setup in the template to show each time a new sidebar widget is inserted. (It shows around each new widget)

```
<div class="sidebox-top"></div>
<div class="sidebox">
   <div class="widgets">
      <div class="textwidget">
      [WIDGET CONTENT]
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The above displays the following CSS:

```
.sidebox-top {
    background-image: url("/images/top-border-side.gif");
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 4px;
}
.sidebox {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
    border-left: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
    border-right: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
    padding: 10px 18px 5px;
}
```

The result is this:

[image: CSS/HTML Result]

This works great for most all widgets used. However, I want the above images to show in the sidebar without the sidebox-top blue line or border. I know there is a way to use certain CSS symbols to identify before or after by using the > symbol, I'm just not sure how to use that here or if it will even work.

Any help is always appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you can't simply use `display:none;` for `.sidebox-top`, use `margin-top:-4px;` for `.sidebox`. But I'm guessing you have some kind of other restriction not yet mentioned.

Comment: Well I don't want to hide those styles for all other uses. Just when I add this new image. I can add a specific DIV or Class around the image but I'm not sure how to tell is to not display the border when this DIV is inside.

Comment: Just create a more specific rule for the image. Give the image a class or unique ID then target that selector to not have the border.

Answer (score 3):

### Replicating the issue

Okay, I've attempted to replicate your image in [this JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/qRKYA/). In case JSFiddle is down, here is what this looks like:

[image: Example Image of Replication]

For this instead of using a `background-image` and 4px `height` on `.sidebox-top`, I've simply used a 4px `border-top`. Whilst not an identical replication, this achieves the same basic effect.

### Hiding the `.sidebox-top` element

#### Step 1

To begin with, we need to target the very first child contained within the `.textwidget` divider, *only* if it's an `img`. We do not want to apply this styling to any other `img` elements after that, nor do we want to apply the styling if the `img` isn't the first element within the container. To do this, we can use:

```css
.textwidget img:first-child { ... }
```

#### Step 2

The next step is to give our image top padding and negative top margin equal to the sum of the top padding of `.sidebox` and the height of `.sidebox-top`. We then want to give our image a background which is the same colour as the background of your widget:*

```css
.textwidget img:first-child {
    background: #fff;
    padding-top:14px;
    margin-top: -14px;
}
```

***** *Note: This assumes that your widget's background is the same as your widget's container's background and that the background is a solid colour. If it isn't, you'll need to play around with `background-position` to align your patterned background with the widget's background.*

From this, we end up with our image overlapping the top border whilst remaining in the same position that it started in:

[image: Step 2 Figure]

#### Step 3

The third step is to cover the entire `.sidebox-top`. To do this we're going to need to give our selected `img` left and right padding and negative left and right margin equal to the sum of the left and right padding of the `.sidebox` and its border-width:

```css
.textwidget img:first-child {
    ... /* Styling from Step 2 */

    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-right: 18px;
    margin-left: -19px;
    margin-right: -19px;
}
```

[image: Step 3 Figure]

#### Step 4

Step 3 has certainly covered the entire `.sidebox-top`, but it's also covered the borders of `.sidebox`. For this we need to add identical borders to our selected `img` and reduce the left and right padding on our `img` to allow for this:

```css
.textwidget img:first-child {
    ... /* Styling from Step 2 */

    padding-left: 17px;
    padding-right: 17px;

    ... /* Margins from Step 3 */

    border-left: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
    border-right: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
}
```

[image: Step 4 Figure]

#### Final Step

The final step is to add a top border to our `img` to complete the border of the widget. As with Step 4, for this we'll need to reduce the size of the top padding to allow for this border:

```css
.textwidget img:first-child {
    ... /* Styling from previous steps */

    padding-top: 13px;
    border-top: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
}
```

[image: Final Result]

[**Final JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/qRKYA/1/).